# iOS: Apply color effect on top of views from a different view hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm searching for a code sample (if this idea is even possible) how to create an affect such as I will try now to explain:

Lets say I've got a `view (A)` with a background color and a label on it. The label can be black or white. Now from a different view hierarchy I have an `overlay view (B)` which is on top of that colored view with the label (can't change the color of the label). Is it possible to apply an effect on the current `view (B)` so that every color from the background `view (A)` will change to a different one. It is hard to describe that behavior. It is like the hue/saturation overlay in photoshop, but it should work for black and white colors of the label (this is important). I hope this can be done without taking snapshots and any images, because the label is dynamic.

It is possible to set the background color of the `(B) view` with some transparency so the label is not fully black or white and apply the effect afterwards on top of that.

I'd appreciate if someone can lead me from here or knows of a possible code sample. I don't know the keywords for that problem so I could search more by myself.

Swift is preferred but I can translate Objective-C to Swift as well.

**UPDATE:**

I guess I'm searching for blending mode here, which is not really possible without performance decrease. :/ Correct me If I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at using a CIFilter called [CIColorMap](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorMap). It allows you to map a monochrome image to new colors.

Comment: The probleme here is that the view in background is dynamic and can resize and the label can change at unknown time, so I can't capture images and apply the effect on captured image. :( Right now I'm trying to put an SKView on top with transparency allowed and some blending sprites, but not sure if this will work out.

Comment: I see, yes, that's a limitation of CALayer on iOS. SpriteKit does allow live filters, but I think the filter only applies to children nodes. Good luck!

Comment: SKSpriteNode blending seems only to work inside own node hierarchy and does not affect the visible background view hierarchy. Too good to be true.